# Brick Compendium: BIONICLE LEGO

Tags: part-identification, bionicle

Is there a comprehensive compendium of the old Bionicle pieces?

For example, what is the part name for:

- Tahu Mata's flame sword?
- Lewa Nuva's twin blades?
- The Zamor Sphere's holder, as used by the Toa Ignika?
- The Midak Skyblaster?
- The zipcord whirly-peg thing for the spinners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find most LEGO pieces, including those that are specific to the Bionicle theme [on Peeron](http://peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/psearch?query=bionicle&limit=parts).
For example here are your particular mentions:

- [Technic Bionicle Weapon Flame Sword 2 x 12](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/32558)
- [Technic Bionicle Weapon Blade 12L](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/44033)
- [Technic Bionicle Toa Inika Zamor Sphere Magazine](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/53550)
- [Technic Bionicle Weapon Midak Skyblaster with Black Housing](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/60932cx1)
- [Technic Bionicle Rhotuka Spinner Ripcord 12L with Hand Grip](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/50900)